# Object Declaration in my class with addafruit Motor libary

Tags: c++, arduino

```
 class JAAmtr {
  private:
    boolean lefton;
  public:
    JAAmtr();
    void turnleft();
    void turnright();
    boolean getLefton();
 };
```

Hi,
Im writing this class to make my arduino robot turn left or right.

where do I put the code for the motor Assignment(I want it into my class):

```
 AF_DCMotor motor1(1);
 AF_DCMotor motor2(2);
 AF_DCMotor motor3(3);
 AF_DCMotor motor4(4);
```

I tried it as private variables but it was not working.
Thank you for your answers

here is my code:

```
#include <AFMotor.h>


 // pin assignments
 int PhotoR1 = 1;
 int PhotoR2 = 5;

     **//Following 4lines into my class**
     AF_DCMotor motor1(1);
     AF_DCMotor motor2(2);
     AF_DCMotor motor3(3);
     AF_DCMotor motor4(4); 


 class JAAmtr {
  private:
    boolean lefton;
  public:
    JAAmtr();
    void turnleft();
    void turnright();
    boolean getLefton();
 };

void setup(){

 JAAmtr viermotor; 

 pinMode(PhotoR1, INPUT);
 pinMode(PhotoR2, INPUT);
 Serial.begin(9600);  


}

//LOOP:
void loop(){
 int light0 = analogRead(PhotoR1);
 int light1 = analogRead(PhotoR2);
 Serial.print(light0);
 Serial.print(" <-R1 R5-> ");
 Serial.println(light1);
 if( light0 > light1 )
 {

 } else {


}
  delay(500);
}
//END LOOP

JAAmtr::JAAmtr(){  
 motor1.setSpeed(200); //Turn on the Motor
 motor1.run(RELEASE);
 motor2.setSpeed(200); //Turn on the Motor
 motor2.run(RELEASE);
 motor3.setSpeed(200); //Turn on the Motor
 motor3.run(RELEASE);
 motor4.setSpeed(200); //Turn on the Motor
 motor4.run(RELEASE);

}

void JAAmtr::turnleft(){
    if(lefton == false)
    {
        motor1.run(RELEASE);
        motor2.run(RELEASE);
        motor3.run(RELEASE);
        motor4.run(RELEASE);
        delay(500);
        lefton = true;
    }
        motor1.run(BACKWARD);
        motor2.run(BACKWARD);
        motor3.run(FORWARD);
        motor4.run(FORWARD);

}

void JAAmtr::turnright(){
    if(lefton == true)
    {
        motor1.run(RELEASE);
        motor2.run(RELEASE);
        motor3.run(RELEASE);
        motor4.run(RELEASE);
        delay(500);
        lefton = false;
    }
        motor3.run(BACKWARD);
        motor4.run(BACKWARD);
        motor1.run(FORWARD);
        motor2.run(FORWARD);

}

//MOVE FORWARD FUCNTION
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it was not working"?

Comment: Expected: some idea of what you were trying to do.  Tried:  to understand "where do I put the code for the motor Assignment(I want it into my class): ... I tried it as private variables ...."  Result: couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the private section, declare the member variables

```
AF_DCMotor motor1;
AF_DCMotor motor2;
AF_DCMotor motor3;
AF_DCMotor motor4;
```

Then in the constructor, initialize them

```
JAAmtr::JAAmtr() : motor1(1), motor2(2), motor3(3), motor4(4)
{  
    motor1.setSpeed(200); //Turn on the Motor
    motor1.run(RELEASE);
    motor2.setSpeed(200); //Turn on the Motor
    motor2.run(RELEASE);
    motor3.setSpeed(200); //Turn on the Motor
    motor3.run(RELEASE);
    motor4.setSpeed(200); //Turn on the Motor
    motor4.run(RELEASE);

}
```

Comment: Thanks thats what Im trying to do but now I get the following error: In constructor 'JAAmtr::JAAmtr()':
LightFollow_P_Controller:54: error: no matching function for call to 'AF_DCMotor::AF_DCMotor()'
Arduino/libraries/AFMotor/AFMotor.h:156: note: candidates are: AF_DCMotor::AF_DCMotor(uint8_t, uint8_t)